# The argument type 'Iterable<Map<String, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the below function to take List data from API call and populate pop-up metadata with the first 5 instances of key/value pairs.

```
   var mappedList = boards.boards!.take(5).toList(); 


   // now, from the list above, I map each result into a key-value pair

    var mappedValues = mappedList.map((m) => { 'headsign': m.getString('headsign'), 'time': m.getString('time') });

   // this list will look like:
   // [{ headsign: 'value1', title: 'title1'}, { headsign: 'value2', title: 'value2' }]


   // Now moving mappedValues list to showDialog
   String title = ("Title Test");

   _DropDownList(mappedValues, title);
   });
  }


  Future<void> _DropDownList(List<Map<String, dynamic>> values, String title) async {
         var test1 = ListBody(
              ...
```

I receive the error

```
    The argument type 'Iterable<Map<String, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'
```

on the line

```
     _DropDownList(mappedValues, title); //(on 'mappedValues')
```

This error links to

```
   var mappedValues = mappedList.map((m) =>
```

And the error is with the `map` section of the function. I have tried casting `as` etc but can't get it to work or go through as a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`

Thanks

**Update**

If I change to iterable like so I get the error `The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Iterable<Map<String, dynamic>>'.` on `[index]` where highlighted below

```
Future<void> _DropDownList(Iterable<Map<String, dynamic>> values, String title) async {
         var test1 = ListBody(
              children: List.generate(
                values.length, (index) {
   *[index]*                return Text(values[index]['headsign']);
                }
              ),
            );
```

Thanks

Comment: A `List` is one type of `Iterable`, but not all `Iterable`s are `List`s.  Does your `_DropDownList` function actually need to take a `List` argument, or could it take an `Iterable` instead?  If so, I'd just change `_DropDownList`'s parameter type to be more general.  Otherwise you'll need to create a `List` from the `Iterable` by calling [`.toList()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Iterable/toList.html) on it.

Comment: Thanks, have updated Q with what happened when I tried that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily change an `Iterable` to a list by calling `toList()` so just change

```
var mappedValues = mappedList.map((m) => { 'headsign': m.getString('headsign'), 'time': m.getString('time') });
```

to

```
var mappedValues = mappedList.map((m) => { 'headsign': m.getString('headsign'), 'time': m.getString('time') }).toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try to add .toList for the map type list. Something like this -

```
var mappedValues = mappedList.map((m) => { 'headsign': m.getString('headsign'), 'time': m.getString('time') }).toList();
```